# How to unmodify a modified master page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2013 when a master page is modified eg: oslo.master, it moves to the content database. I know is is not good practice to modify the default master pages. But once that have been done how do we unmodify them and have them in the windows file system in the 15 hive folder.

Comment: It is called Ghosting and Unghosting, search for those terms

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharePoint Designer. Navigate to the master page gallery, right click on master page, and choose **"Reset to site definition"**:

[image]